# Continuity of norm of continuous random variable

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, probability-theory, normed-spaces

Suppose I have a continuous random variable $X \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Let the norm function $f$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ be the Euclidean norm, i.e. $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to [0,\infty)$ such that $f(x) = \sqrt{x^T x} \text{ } \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$.

Since $X$ is a continuous random variable, we know that $\mathrm{cdf}_{X}(\cdot)$ is a continuous function, which means that that $\mathrm{pdf}_{X}(\cdot)$ exists a.e. and is non-negative where defined.

Note: By $\mathrm{cdf}_{X}(x)$, I mean
$\mathrm{cdf}_{X}(x) = p\left(X_1\leq x_1, ..., X_n\leq x_n\right)$. Maybe in the real analysis community that's called a distribution function - I'm not sure.

My goal is to show that $Y \doteq f(X)$ is a continuous random variable, i.e. to show that $\mathrm{cdf}_{Y}(\cdot)$ is a continuous function.

Which would be a good way to show that? My intuition tells me that $\mathrm{pdf}_{Y}(\cdot)$ exists a.e. and is non-negative where defined, and that this would be sufficient to show that $\mathrm{cdf}_{Y}(\cdot)$ is continuous. However, I am having a hard time figuring out how to prove that.

Another way I thought of proving that would be perhaps showing how 1) the square of each component of $X$, $X_i^2$, is a continuous random variable, 2) showing how the sum $\sum_i^n X_i^2$ is a continuous random variable, and then 3) showing how $\sqrt{\sum_i^n X_i^2}$ is a continuous random variable. This seems like a much more roundabout, tedious way to go about it. I am also struggling a bit with showing this.

Any pointers or hints would be very much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by the CDF of a random vector? Do you just mean that the distribution of $X$ has density? Or do you simply mean that $X$ has no point-masses? Note that there are one-dimensional distributions with continuous CDF's that are a.e. differentiable with derivative 0.

Comment: I edited the question to clarify your concern. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As stated, you need to be careful with what you actually get by the a.e. existence of a derivative of your CDF. Consider $n>=2$ and $\tilde{X}$ a standard Gaussian on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then $X=\frac{\tilde{X}}{\|X\|}$ defines a random variable which is uniformly distributed on the unit sphere. Hence, $\sqrt{X^T X}$ has a degenerate distribution.

However, it's quite obvious that the CDF of $X$ is continuous, since the area of $\mathbb{S}^n$ contained in a tube of width $\varepsilon$ tends to $0$ as $\varepsilon$ does so (that's simply continuity of measures).

Comment: I guess my comments with the cdf were meant to show my reasoning on the subject. Really, what I care about is to show that, given a multivariate random variable that is continuous, whether its norm is continuous. If that's not generally true, I would like to figure out what conditions need to be imposed in order to make that happen. Should I amend my question, or should delete my question and make a new one?

Comment: Also, in the example that you gave, how is the cdf of X continuous? It would seem to me that this would not be a continuous random variable, since all of the probability mass would be contained within a set of zero measure.

Comment: @UlisesNunez In order for the CDF to be continuous according to your definition, the support of the distribution would have to lie on a hyper-plane. However, the $X$ above has $0$ probability of lying in any given hyper-plane.

Answer (score 1):

$G_Y(y)=P(Y\le y)=P(f(X)\le y)=P(X\le f^{-1} (y))=F_X(f^{-1}(y))=F_X(f^{-1} (y))$

This is continuous only when $f$ is a one-to-one function so it has an inverse. If f is decreasing then f inverse increases and the cdf makes sense. But if f is increasing then  f inverse decreases and the cdf of y makes no sense.